# I created a Library application using MERN. I want to input a photo for my every book in the list

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

[image: my book list]

I m developing a book list . I ask the user to enter name and author and isbn no and image for each book. user select image from his device and upload it, each image should display in the list with book name and author . there is an error images are not showing in the list
I want to add an image for each book in the list. I developed front end input fields.
but it is not working.

This is is the code I developed

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const path = require("path");
let BooksModel = require("./Books/books");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, uuidv4() + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const allowdFileTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"];
  if (allowdFileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

let upload = multer({ storage, fileFilter });

router.route("/add").post(upload.single("photo"), (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const author = req.body.author;
  const isbn_no = req.body.isbn_no;
  const photo = req.body.photo;

  const newUserData = {
    name,
    author,
    isbn_no,
    photo,
  };

  const newUser = new User(newUserData);
  newUser
    .save()
    .then(() => res.json("User Added"))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("error: " + err));
});

router.route("/rec").get((req, res) => {
  User.find()
    .then(() => res.json(user))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).json("error: " + err));
});
```

.

Comment: Are you saving the new user with correct path for the photo? Try and console log it.